# random associative array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, random, multidimensional-array, associative-array

So I have an array of arrays and a foreach loop and im trying to take the results of that and randomly pick an array item and display it.

In the example below after the foreach loop, three fruits are displayed and now one of them should be picked at random and be displayed but it shows the word "**array**" instead of one of the fruit names.

EDITED: **ANSWERED AND EDITED**

```
<?php

$fruit = array (

array("apple",1,0),
array("orange",0,0),
array("watermelon",0,0),
array("peach",0,0)
  );

foreach ($fruit as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[1] > 0) {unset($fruit[$key]); }
}

echo $fruit[0][0]."<br>";
echo $fruit[1][0]."<br>";
echo $fruit[2][0]."<br>";
echo $fruit[3][0]."<br>";



//EDIT ANSWER BELOW!
$x = mt_rand(0, 3);
echo  $fruit[$x][0]."<br>"; 

?>
```

Comment: Since you have an array of arrays, `$fruit[$fruitoftheday]` is an `array`, not scalar value

Comment: Hey thanks i figured it out.. posted the answer and gave you credit for kick starting the mouse on the treadmill in my head.